# Why is my connection to php-fpm.sock being refused?

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, php5, docker

I've seen a bunch of questions about this problem on here but none of those had answers that helped me out.

I kept getting a 502 error from nginx so I took a look at the access.log and saw I kept getting error 111 when the server tried to connect to `unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock`

I've restarted php5-fpm and made sure that the socket is actually there but I keep getting this error.

Do you guys know why?

My nginx.conf

```
user www-data www-data;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx_error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;

  fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
  fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";

  access_log /var/logs/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/logs/nginx/access.log;

  server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /var/www/app/public/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm =404;

    server_name localhost;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri /index.php =404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }

  }
}
```

and the php-fpm.conf [here](http://sprunge.us/IXVi)

Comment: What is your php-fpm configuration?

Comment: Just the default one that ships with `php5-fpm` on ubuntu. I haven't touched that file

Comment: Perhaps you _should_ touch that file. At the least, you should post its contents.

Comment: There ya go. Sorry about that

Comment: That is _not_ the php-fpm configuration!

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed

Comment: OK, where's the rest of it?

Comment: That's all of it... I used `cat` to send it to sprunge... so that's all of it...

Comment: No, it's not. You forgot the `include`d files, which are where the important bits are.

Comment: Do you have any idea of what's wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31218/discussion-between-thecodethinker-and-michael-hampton).

Answer (score 0):

`php5-fpm` uses `SCRIPT_FILENAME` to find the path to the php file to interpret. I notice that you have that line commented out. Is that an oversight or has that line been moved to the `fastcgi_params` include file?